# LINQ to SQL GroupBy: connection timeout

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, connection-timeout

I just wrote what I thought to be a very simple query:

```
public IList<Departement> GetDepartements()  
{
    IQueryable<MyContext> queryBase = QueryBase();

    IQueryable<Departement> query = 
        (from x in queryBase
         group x by x.Geographies.DepartementCode
         into grp
         select new Departement
             {
                 code = grp.Key,
                 numberOfDistributors =
                     grp.Select(x=> x.Distributors.Distributeur_PK)
                        .Count(),
                 numberOfLeads =
                     grp.Select(x=> x.Leads.DemandeWeb_FK).Count()
             }
        );
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Unfortunately I get a connection timeout error.

I do not want to change the DataContext.CommandTimeout property, as I feel it shouldn't be necessary for such a simple query.

Any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 3):

Start a SQL Profiler and catch the sent sql command.
Then execute the command manually in the SQL Management Studio, then you can see how long it will take to execute it. It'll probably run longer than your current CommandTimeout.
After this you have two options:

- Either increase the CommandTimeout
- Come up with another solution which retrieves the data part by part or increase the overall performance of the query itself (indexes, structure)

Comment: Thank you, I'll report on my findings.